# why is there a duplicated java package entry for maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm  using  eclipse neon3 and maven 3.2.1 .

I tried to create  a new maven project by following

```
new->maven->maven project.
```

then  i created a  new java class under etender package,there are 2 duplicated  java package entry and they are  in different color

[[image: 2 package entry for java package]]

i have tried many times , but have the same issue, anyone can tell me why that happens?

Comment: Really using Maven 3.0.1 ? If yes please upgrade asap to Maven 3.5.0 or 3.3.9...

Comment: the eclipse uses the embedded maven of 3.3.9 and i updated to 3.5 and it fixs my problem

Answer (score 0):

update to maven 3.5 and change eclipse to use external maven install fix this problem